# Insert yyyyMMdd string into date column using Talend

Tags: postgresql, date, talend

I have the follow situation:

- A PostgreSQL database with a table that contains a date type column called date.
- A string from a delimited .txt file outputting: 20170101.

I want to insert the string into the date type column.

So far i have tried the following with mixed results/errors:

---

```
row1.YYYYMMDD 
Detail Message: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Date
```

**Explanation**: This one is fairly obvious.

---

```
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyyMMdd",row1.YYYYMMDD) 
Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "data" ("location_id","date","avg_winddirection","avg_windspeed","avg_temperature","min_temperature","max_temperature","total_hours_sun","avg_precipitation") VALUES (209,2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000 +01:00:00,207,7.7,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

can see the string parsed into **"2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000 +01:00:00"**.

When I try to execute the query directly i get a "SQL Error: 42601: ERROR: Syntax error at "00" position 194"

---

**Other observations/attempts:**

The funny thing is if I use '20170101' as a string in the query it works, see below.

```
INSERT INTO "data" ("location_id","date","avg_winddirection","avg_windspeed","avg_temperature","min_temperature","max_temperature","total_hours_sun","avg_precipitation") VALUES (209,'20170101',207,7.7,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

I've also tried to change the schema of the database date column to string. It produces the following:

```
Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "data" ("location_id","date","avg_winddirection","avg_windspeed","avg_temperature","min_temperature","max_temperature","total_hours_sun","avg_precipitation") VALUES (209,20170101,207,7.7,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

This query also doesn't work directly because the date isn't between single quotes.

---

What am i missing or not doing? 
(I've started learning to use Talend 2-3 days ago)

EDIT//
Screenshots of my Job and tMap

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbaQY.jpg

EDIT//It doesnt appear to be a date formatting problem but a Talend to PostgreSQL connection problem

**EDIT//
FIXED: It was a stupid easy problem/solution ofcourse. THe database name and schema name fields were empty... so it basically didnt know where to connect**

Comment: Have you correctly defined datatype for row1.YYYYMMDD in Talend schema?

Comment: I tried string AND date on both schema's.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Talend job?

Comment: Job and tMap: http://imgur.com/a/kSFd0

Comment: could you try to change the DatePattern for the column date in the tMap?

Comment: To what? The parseDate function generates "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000 +01:00:00"

Comment: in the screenshot, you have "dd-MM-yyyy" as DatePattern...

Comment: Well, TalendDate.parseDate() generates "2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000 +01:00:00". I could use TalendDate.formatDate() to change it to dd-MM-yyyy but the function returns a String and then i get the String into date not allowed error :(

Comment: in tMap, lower right corner in your image, there is an option called 'DatePatter', try to change that conforming to the format you used to parse your date

Comment: I've decided to remake the job with only 1 column transfer and i don't think the date is the issue... atleast not anymore. I get the same error transferring only the STN value to the location_id column.

The query works directly but i get the same Batch 0... error

Comment: The `yyyyMMdd` format is dependable enough that you can just insert the dashes between around the month and it becomes standard SQL date. Just surround it with single quotes and you're done. No need to parse it as one date format, then print it as another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: It was a stupid easy problem/solution ofcourse. THe database name and schema name fields were empty... so it basically didnt know where to connect thats why i got the BATCH 0 error and when i went deeper while debugging i found it couldnt find the table, stating the relation didnt exist.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do anything to insert a string like `20170101` into a date column. PostgreSQL will handle it for you it's just ISO 8601's date format.

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( x date );
INSERT INTO foo (x) VALUES ( '20170101' );
```

This is just a talend problem, if anything.

Comment: Indeed, I also came to that conclusion. I hope someone with Talend experience/knowledge will show up.

Comment: It was indeed a Talend problem. A completely different problem though. It didn't have the database name and schema name so it didn't know where to connect.

Answer (score 0):

> [..] (209,**2017-01-01 00:00:00.000000 +01:00:00**,207,7.7,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)[..]

If Talend doesn't know by itself that passing timestamp into query requires it to be single quoted, then if possible - you need to do it.

Comment: That's the thing. I just started learning Talend so i;ve got no idea how to "manually" add the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

[image]

The data in input file is:  20170101(in String format)

then set the tMap like,
[image]

The output is as follows:

[image]